# Run a JS function while in viewport.

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, viewport

I've found on here how to do a counter, and I will be using it on a scrolling site.

I'm using the following code:

```
$(function() {
    function count($this){
        var current = parseInt($this.html(), 10);
        $this.html(++current);
        if(current !== $this.data('count')){
        setTimeout(function(){count($this)}, 10);
    }   
}
  $("span").each(function() {
  $(this).data('count', parseInt($(this).html(), 10));
  $(this).html('0');
  count($(this));
  });
});
```

I've tried to include the following code, but I'm not sure I'm adding it correctly:

```
      if ($('element').visible(true)) {

}
```

Heres a link to the Jfiddle that is currently working without the if statement. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/WpJxn/257/

Comment: What does **viewport** have to do with anything?  Expand your question to be a bit clearer.  If you want the activity to only happen when the element is visible, then you will need a trigger that fires your `if` statement - probably [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) is your best bet.

Comment: I've checked your fiddle - what is it exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: This is going to go on a one page scrolling site and is at the bottom of the page. So I would like to trigger the count up when someone scrolls to that specific section. It would be pointless to run the JS when no one is able to see it.

Comment: As a visual example if it were to go on this site in the contact section.
http://rockets-are-red.com/

Since you have to scroll to see the contact content. I would like it to wait to run the count till you see that section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you should look at: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Here is an example for you that demonstrates this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/XYS2G/ - just try to scroll the Result window.

HTML:

```
<div class="indicators">
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section1">section1</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section2">section2</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section3">section3</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section4">section4</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section5">section5</span>
    <span class="indicator" data-id="section6">section6</span>
</div>
<div class="sections">
    <div class="section" id="section1">section1</div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">section2</div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">section3</div>
    <div class="section" id="section4">section4</div>
    <div class="section" id="section5">section5</div>
    <div class="section" id="section6">section6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.indicators { position: fixed; }
.section { height: 150px; }
```

JavaScript:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

function refreshIndicators() {
    $('.indicator').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView($('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')))) {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        } else {
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        }
    });
}

refreshIndicators();

$(window).bind('scroll', refreshIndicators);
```